# div content on bootstrap pophover with id issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, smarty

I follow jävi's post on [div on bootstrap pophover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875376/is-it-possible-to-use-a-div-as-content-for-twitters-popover) but don't know how to put id for whole divs. I actually want when mouseover to language name Cantonese or English will pophover Reading,Writing,Listening,Speaking with their progressbars. Due to Smarty foreach, I can't put id=popover_content_wrapper to each of skill...

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/6TaQt/14/

**CODE:**

```
{foreach from=$complexElements key="complexElementKey" item="complexElementItem"}
   <div class="row-fluid">

{foreach from=$form_fields item=form_field}
{if $form_field.caption == "Language Name"}
  <h4><a class='danger' data-placement='above' title="Popover Title" href='#'>{display property=$form_field.id complexParent=$complexField complexStep=$complexElementKey}</a>&nbsp;</h4>
{else}
    <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none" style="display:inline">
        <label class="span4" for="slider">[[$form_field.caption]]</label>
            <div class="span8"> 
              <div class="progress progress-info progress-striped" rel="tooltip" title="{display property=$form_field.id complexParent=$complexField complexStep=$complexElementKey}%">
                <div class="bar" style="width: {display property=$form_field.id complexParent=$complexField complexStep=$complexElementKey}%;"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
  </div>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line style attribute defined two times , make that single , I am not sure , hope it helps

```
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none" style="display:inline">
```

Comment: Yuh I am asking how to define once or use any new method.

Comment: Try this : <div id="popover_content_wrapper_{$form_field.id}" style="display: none">

Comment: So I have to put multiple return $('#popover_content_wrapper_xxx').html(); inside content: function()?

Comment: Yes.. while you giving **{$form_field.id}** you can get dynamic div id , so you can make it for your needs