# How to show a specific element on Bootstrap Popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I would like to show the bootstrap tab inside the Popover. I referred to the Bootstrap documentation and am not able to acheive this correctly. Following is the code that I have tried

http://jsfiddle.net/p57pD/1/

```
var tab = $('#mytab');
$('#mypop').popover({
    selector: tab
});
```

Am not sure what is the mistake that I am doing to get this working. Appreciate if someone could help me understand the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the selector; you can use this:

```
$('#mypop').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#mytab').html();
    }
})
```

Note that the div should have `id="mytab"` and not `class="mytab"` as in your fiddle.

A working sample (forked from your fiddle) is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/serra/uKMC3).

Takeaways:

1. set `html = true` to allow html inside the popover.
2. use the `content` function to return the the html - which in your case comes from a hidden div
3. don't use the selector option for this; it's a bit confusing (to me at least), but it is not intended to use with elements that are already in the dom as in your example [ref 1](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2091) [ref2](http://jsfiddle.net/KPeKS/4/)

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875376/is-it-possible-to-use-a-div-as-content-for-twitters-popover