# Can Bootstrap 3 popovers use an external div for content?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

All of the examples here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers use inline content for the popovers with the `data-content` attribute.

What I'd like to do is set up a hidden `div` on my page with the content, and target that from the popover trigger, like:

```
<div id="myPopoverContent">
   ...stuff...
</div>
```

and then

```
<a ng-href="" data-toggle="popover"><span class="badge">12</span> You have 12 messages.</a>
```

as the trigger.  But how to trigger?

Comment: send an ajax call and then on success trigger click programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a div as content for Twitter's Popover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875376/is-it-possible-to-use-a-div-as-content-for-twitters-popover)

Comment: I saw that post, it wasn't quite what I was looking for though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `content` option of the `popover` function to pass the content:

```
{
    content: $('#myPopoverContent').text()
}
```

To be able to use HTML content, use:

```
{
    content: $('#myPopoverContent').html(),
    html: true
}
```

I’ve prepared a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7ekRN/) for you.

Comment: Just a note: you do not need `data-toggle="popover"` or the click event when using the `.popover(options)` function. But nice work otherwise! +1 http://jsfiddle.net/7ekRN/2/

Comment: I know. I just didn’t want to mess with the OP’s HTML.

Comment: Nice.  Can this be generalize so I only can have one jquery function that simply calls a div named in the trigger element? Let's say I create `data-pop="#myDiv"` to call `div id="myDiv"` and a different data-pop attribute for a different div -- using the same jQuery handler.  I'd rather not have a handler for every popover if I can help it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this should work if you make the `content` option [a function](http://jsfiddle.net/7ekRN/4/): `{content: function() { return $(this.dataset.pop).html(); }), html: true}`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. There was an error with brackets or parens when I tried to add your code, but it ultimately works great: http://pastie.org/9112266

Comment: saved my behind today. Thanks!