# Insert external HTML txt into popover content and go to Tag in Wordpress (no iframe)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I got the code working in the [w3schools Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide), but in WordPress 4.3.1 I can't get it to jump to the tag. I am quite a beginner to this so I am asking for help here. I want to insert HTML from an .txt file and jump to section X using #Term-X. It's a glossary. My code is based on [this answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8908888).
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.glossary').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#pcw').html(); // pcw = popover_content_wrapper 
    }
  });
  $('#pcw').load("http:// — myURL — .txt");
  $("a").click(function(){
    $(this).popover('show');    
  });
});
</script>

<style>
.popover-content {
      width:250px; 
      height:250px;
      overflow: auto; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<a class='glossary' data-placement='auto' href='#Term-X'>Term I want to show in Popover</a>
<div id="pcw" style="display: none"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my .txt script in the external file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

<!-- some CSS here -->

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box" id="Term1">
    <div class="title"><b>Term1</b></div>
    <div class="description">soandso</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="Term2">
    <div class="title"><b>Term2</b></div>
    <div class="description">soandso</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="Term3">
    <div class="title"><b>Term3</b></div>
    <div class="description">soandso</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the html document line 11 the character after the word glossary is not

> '

Fix it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.glossary').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#pcw').html(); // pcw = popover_content_wrapper 
    }
  });
  $('#pcw').load("http:// — myURL — .txt");
  $("a").click(function(){
    $(this).popover('show');    
  });
});
</script>

<style>
.popover-content {
      width:250px; 
      height:250px;
      overflow: auto; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<a class='glossary' data-placement='auto' href='#Term-X'>Term I want to show in Popover</a>
<div id="pcw" style="display: none"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just got wrong here. Thats not the problem. Script is working, just not working in Wordpress 4.3.1.

Comment: so, now tell me how you are implementing them in wordpress.

Comment: I used the "Raw HTML" parser from the "WPBakery Visual Composer".

Comment: let me see the output page, it will be better if you share it on live domain.

Comment: um, don't know how to…