# How would I create a dropdown menu with text input area in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, sass

I'd like to recreate this same type of dropdown menu in AngularJS. I've made the button with FontAwesome icons nested in there. Any ideas?  Links to resource?

[DropDown Text Input Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUmVK.png)

```js
var mainApp = angular.module( "mainApp", ["ngRoute"] );

mainApp.controller( "CategoriesController", [ "$scope", "dataFactory", function( $scope, dataFactory ) {

mainApp.controller("Menu", function( $scope ) {
    $scope.showMenu0 = false;
$scope.revealMenu0 = function( listing ) {
      $scope.showMenu0 = !$scope.showMenu0;
  
   }
})
}]);
```

```css
.burgerbtn{
 position: absolute;
    display:block;
 margin-left: 19%;
 margin-top: -17.5%;
 height: 26px;
 width: 44px;
 color: #a09c98;
 font-size: 1em;
 border-radius: 13%;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-mouseover="revealMenu0()" ng-mouseleave="hideMenu0()">
        <img src={imageurl;}>
      </div>
<span ng-show="showMenu0">
        <button class="burgerbtn" ><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </span>
```

Comment: Take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/eGohFqiGKmkonmLwT3g1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for piecing that together @developer033, however, that's not quite what I'm looking for.  Even though my code snippet doesn't work properly, the button appears on hover.  I just need to be able to but a text input area beneath the button on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to show the menu on button click or on hover?

Either way this is more about CSS than angular. 
You angular code seems to make sense as far as toggling the menu. To make a drop down you can do something like this:

***Template:***

```
<span class="dd-btn" ng-click="revealMenu0()">
  <i>btnIcon</i>

  //notice the menu is inside the button!
  <div class="dd-menu" ng-if="showMenu0">
   //insert menu content here
  </div>
</span>
```

***CSS:***

```
.dd-btn {
  position: relative;
}

.dd-menu {
  // this will make the menu stick to the bottom of the button 
  // you can set margin to 0 if you don't want a gap between.
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

That should be all you need to get it to look like a dropdown, you can add more to make it look pretty.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me.  Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: What didn't work exactly?

Comment: This is pretty close to what I originally wrote. Is this not what you are trying to achieve? http://codepen.io/matthsiung/pen/bZomVK

Comment: That works!!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: No problem! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a front-end framework? I recommend [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Bootstrap's [Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) feature does what you want - you can [insert HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875376/is-it-possible-to-use-a-div-as-content-for-twitters-popover) into the Popover instead of just text.